# Need catx macro function - catx is limited to 200 characters in proc sql

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

It can be kind a dummy question but I can not find example.
The case is below:

```
proc sql;
   create table set1 as select catx('<', field1, field2 ....) as need_field
   from table;
quit;
```

With this code field need_field cuts up tо length 200, so its predictible as documentation says:

> The CATX function returns a value to a variable, or returns a value in
>   a temporary buffer. The value that is returned from the CATX function
>   has the following length:
>
> •up to 200 characters in WHERE clauses and in PROC SQL
>
> •up to 32767 characters in the DATA step except in WHERE clauses
>
> •up to 65534 characters when CATX is called from the macro processor

I do not want do use data step. Could you help me to built code using macro processor? (third way). Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `catx` can return more than 200 characters if `length=` is specified but all data must fit in column. Otherwise you will get empty value.

Proof:

```
data test;
   length a b c $400;
   a = repeat('A',300);
   b = repeat('B',300);
   c = repeat('C',300);
   output;
   a = repeat('A',350);
   b = repeat('B',350);
   c = repeat('C',350);
   output;
run;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select catx('<', a, b, c) as temp_list length=1000
   from test;
quit;

data _null_;
   set want;
   a = length(temp_list);
   put a=;
run;
```

In documentation there is also this:

> If CATX returns a value in a temporary buffer, the length of the
>   buffer depends on the calling environment, and the value in the buffer
>   can be truncated after CATX finishes processing. In this case, SAS
>   does not write a message about the truncation to the log. If the
>   length of the variable or the buffer is not large enough to contain
>   the result of the concatenation, SAS does the following:
>
> - changes the result to a blank value in the DATA step, and in PROC SQL
> - writes a warning message to the log stating that the result was either
>     truncated or set to a blank value, depending on the calling
>     environment
> - writes a note to the log that shows the location of the function call and lists the argument that caused the truncation
> - sets `_ERROR_` to 1 in the DATA step

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own macro function `%CATX`.
Using macros you can generate a code, in this case using `%catx(<, name, sex, name)` I generated `strip(name)||"<"||strip(sex)||"<"||strip(name)` which is very similar thing what is done by regular `catx function`.
Macro with `parmbuff` option takes all aruments and put them in one macro variable which is call `syspbuff`.

```
%macro catx / parmbuff;
    %let comma = %eval(%index(&syspbuff., %str(,))+1);
    %let separator=%scan(&syspbuff., 1, %str(%(%),));
    %let syspbuff=%substr(&syspbuff., &comma., %eval(%length(&syspbuff.)-&comma.));
    %let result = strip(%sysfunc(tranwrd(%bquote(&syspbuff.), %str(,), %str(%)||"&separator."||strip%())));
    &result. 
%mend catx;

proc sql;
    create table a as
    select %catx(<, name, sex, name) as var
    from class;
quit;
```

Comment: This block of code would greatly benefit from an explanation of how it works.

Comment: I have no idea why you'd want to do such a thing, but in any event this fails on numerics.

Comment: @Joe For example, if catx really returned only 200 characters then you have to write `substr(field1) || '<' || substr(field2) || '<' ... '<' || substr(fieldn)` on your own or use this macro to generate it for you. Yes, it will fail on numerics. It still can be adjusted for numerics or send to %catx `put(numeric,format)` instead of numeric.

Comment: If `catx` really didn't work (it does), then I would use FCMP to write a function.

Comment: FCMP functions often have a very poor performance, so sometimes better use a macro.

Answer (score 0):

there is a handy trick where you drop your `cats` column and call it further down as a calculated column.

See this example using `sashelp.class`

```
 proc sql;
  create table want(drop=temp_list) as
  select catx('<', repeat(name,200),repeat(name,200)) as temp_list length=1024,
      put((calculated temp_list),$400.) as need_field length=400
  from sashelp.class
  ;
quit;
```

Example 2:

```
data a; 
length a $1000; 
a = repeat("A", 1000);
run;

proc sql; 
create table b(drop=temp) as select catx('<', a, a) as temp length=2024,
   (calculated temp) as b length=5000 from a; 
quit;
```

hope it helps

Comment: You dont't need to create another collumn. Check my answear.

Comment: I really don't like this solution.  It's very hacky/gimmicky and if someone else comes along and has to work with the code it is not clear why you would be doing that and they could easily break it.

Comment: ...or... you could just do it the right way by defining the length as per fl0r3k's answer.